# apache pointing to wrong version of postgresql

Tags: php, apache, postgresql

I am looking at my PHPinfo.php and it shows that it is pointing to postgres v. 9.2 when I am using postgres v. 8.2

How can I change where php and apache use the correct version of postgres?

Comment: I am using mac osx with php, apache, and postgresql82

Comment: Do you mean the libraries for 9.2? Or an actual pg instance of 9.2?  Pg's libpq is pretty much backwards compatible, so there shouldn't be a problem running a 9.2 based php module against an older db.

Comment: On the other hand, 8.2 is now something like 3 or 4 years out of maintenance, and I would HIGHLY suggest migrating to pg 9.2 or higher. Much faster and it gets bug fixes which 8.2 does not.